# Cakephp redirect not working on virtual host

Tags: apache, cakephp, virtual-hosts

I would like to tell you about the problem I´m having now. 
The thing is that I moved my cakephp project from the test enviroment to the production enviroment, the production server handles some virtual servers. So, i placed my project in D:\xampp\htdocs. And added the following lines in my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@myhost.com.mx
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/enterprise"
    ServerName enterprise.ent.com
    ErrorLog "logs/enterprise.ent.com.log"
    CustomLog "logs/enterprise.ent.com.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem comes when I log in, everything works fine, until I make a redirect with the line:

```
$this->redirect("/Main");
```

This redirect takes me again to the log in page, so this tells me the redirect did not work. 
Does anybody know about this?, could you give some help?

I´m using apache 2.2 over windows server.
Best regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: So its losing session when you redirects it with $this->redirect("/Main"); right ?

Comment: Please post your CakePHP version, and your routes configuration

Comment: @Er.KT It might look It does that, but the sesión is actually stored :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m happy to tell you that I already solved the problem, The thing was that I had configured the session with the following:

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => array(
        'session.cookie_path' => '/enterprise',
    ),
    'cookie' => 'enterprise',
    'cookieTimeout' => 0,   
       'checkAgent'  => false  
));
```

I don´t really know why, but after removing the 'ini' section It Works like a charm :O, so the code goes like follows:

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'enterprise',
    'cookieTimeout' => 0,   
       'checkAgent'  => false  
));
```

I hope this helps someone in the future. Thank you very much for your answers, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your .htaccess files (one in the webroot and one in the root). You can find a detailed explanation in [the cake documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html).